# r text mining extract keywords

Tags: r, csv, text, machine-learning, nlp

I am new to R and working on a machine learning problem, I understand that machine learning requires labelled data to make accurate prediction.

I am working with text data where the reviews given by users for a particular mobile app in text format. My primary task is to first extract the main keywords(features)

The text data is as follows in the CSV file in the 'review' column

```
review1  - "the gps does not work",
review2  - "tracking of phone is inconsistent",
review3  - "the battery is draining fast",
review4  - "the tracks disappear after some time",
review5  - "the app consumes the battery lot because of gps"
```

now I want to extract the feature mentioned in the each review such as
"gps", "tracking", "battery", "tracks","battery gps" and add it as a label next to it respectively in the CSV file; so there would be one more column created in the CSV file as 'Feature'. 
So my CSV will have 2 columns, one review and one feature column that will highlight the feature mentioned in the review.The snapshot of the data in the CSV will be as follows [new csv file data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1VGs.jpg)

I have written a sample code mentioned below for the same but since I need to deal with thousands of reviews I need to get the Feature column in my csv file which will act as a label for feature prediction

```
#Feature Prediction
library(tm)
library(e1071)
texts <- c("the gps does not work",
           "tracking of phone is inconsistent",
           "the battery is draining fast",
           "the tracks disappear after some time",
           "the app consumes the battery a lot")

features <- c("gps", "tracking", "battery", "tracks","battery")
docs <- VCorpus(VectorSource(texts))
# Clean corpus
docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs)
# Transform dtm to matrix to data frame - df is easier to work with
mat.df <- as.data.frame(data.matrix(dtm), stringsAsfactors = FALSE)
# Column bind category (known classification)
mat.df <- cbind(mat.df, features)
View(mat.df)
# Split data by rownumber into two equal portions (Train and Test Data)
train <- sample(nrow(mat.df), ceiling(nrow(mat.df) * .50))
test <- (1:nrow(mat.df))[- train]
# Isolate classifier
cl <- mat.df[, "features"]
# Create model data and remove "features"
modeldata <- mat.df[,!colnames(mat.df) %in% "features"]
feature_pred <- naiveBayes(modeldata[train,], cl[train])
naiv_pred <- predict(feature_pred, modeldata[test,])
conf.mat <- table("Predictions" = naiv_pred, Actual = cl[test])
conf.mat
(accuracy <- sum(diag(conf.mat))/length(test) * 100)
```

Comment: what would happen if two or more features appeared in the same review?

Comment: my stop words will increase so that only the highlighted features would remain and unwanted words will be removed, also, the priority is given to the first mentioned feature only as the assumption is the users mention the malfunction part first in their reviews

Comment: Look here for keyword extraction techniques in R: http://www.bnosac.be/index.php/blog/77-an-overview-of-keyword-extraction-techniques